# How to use Environment Modules without root access?

Tags: installation, centos, make, scientific-linux

For some reason, I have a hard time finding a tutorial on how to manage user software install with Environment Modules (http://modules.sourceforge.net/) without root.

the closest thing is http://www.hpc.cam.ac.uk/user/modules.html

Comment: have you tried `chown` and `chmod`?